# Getting the wrong answer

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python programming. I am taking my first class.  I have to right a program to calculate a persons BMI rating. I have run the calculation on some online calculators and got an answer of 42.61. But with my program I get an answer of 0.05918367346938776.  I have check the calculations in excel and I get the right answer so I know my formula is basically correct. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
weight_str = input("Enter your weight in pounds: ")
height_str = input ("Enter your height in inches: ")
weight = float(weight_str)
height = float(height_str)
weight_in_kilo = (weight * 0.453592) #convert pounds to kg
height_in_meters = (height * 0.0254) #convert inches to meter
bmi = weight / (height**2)
print ("Your BMI is: ",bmi)
```

Thanks for the help to a newbie.

Boliver

Comment: 42.61!? I think you have more problems than BMI calculations!

Answer (score 5):

You are converting the weight to kilos and meters, but using the pounds and inches in the calculation.

```
bmi = weight / (height**2)
```

should be

```
bmi = weight_in_kilo / (height_in_meters**2)
```

For the imperial conversion, Google tell us that the formula is 
`bmi = (weight / (height**2)) *  703`

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You used `weight` and `height` instead of `weight_in_kilo` and `height_in_meters` in your calculation of `bmi`.